# how to update the xml field value at runtime?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

i have the following xml. i want to update weight as 2KG in XML at runtime in Oracle PLSQL. how to do that ?

```
    <XML><FRUIT_SHOP>AZHAGIRI</FRUIT_SHOP>
<FRUITS>
<FRUIT>
<FRUIT_NAME>ORANGE</FRUIT_NAME>
<ORANGE_FIELDS>
<FIELD>
<KEY>COLOUR</KEY>
<VALUE>LIGHT_RED</VALUE>
</FIELD>
<FIELD>
<KEY>WEIGHT</KEY>
<VALUE>1KG</VALUE>
</FIELD>
</DETAIL>
</ORANGE_FIELDS>
</FRUIT>
</FRUITS>
```

Expected

```
<XML><FRUIT_SHOP>AZHAGIRI</FRUIT_SHOP>
<FRUITS>
<FRUIT>
<FRUIT_NAME>ORANGE</FRUIT_NAME>
<ORANGE_FIELDS>
<FIELD>
<KEY>COLOUR</KEY>
<VALUE>LIGHT_RED</VALUE>
</FIELD>
<FIELD>
<KEY>WEIGHT</KEY>
<VALUE>2KG</VALUE>
</FIELD>
</DETAIL>
</ORANGE_FIELDS>
</FRUIT>
</FRUITS>
```

Oracle plsql block should do that ?

Comment: Hello buddy, what did you try up till now?

Comment: Why do you want to use PL/SQL for this, rather than SQL? Where is the XML coming from and where is it going - are you updating a value stored in a table for instance? Anyway, [start with the documentaion](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb04cre.htm#ADXDB512), or the many examples on this and other sites; then if you get stuck show how far you have got and what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use SQL:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/95f3c/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( xml_column ) AS
SELECT XMLTYPE( '<XML>
<FRUIT_SHOP>AZHAGIRI</FRUIT_SHOP>
<FRUITS>
  <FRUIT>
    <FRUIT_NAME>ORANGE</FRUIT_NAME>
    <ORANGE_FIELDS>
      <FIELD><KEY>COLOUR</KEY><VALUE>LIGHT_RED</VALUE></FIELD>
      <FIELD><KEY>WEIGHT</KEY><VALUE>1KG</VALUE></FIELD>
    </ORANGE_FIELDS>
  </FRUIT>
</FRUITS>
</XML>' )
FROM DUAL;

UPDATE table_name
SET xml_column = UPDATEXML(
  xml_column,
  '/XML/FRUITS/FRUIT/ORANGE_FIELDS/FIELD/KEY[text()="WEIGHT"]/../VALUE/text()',
  '2KG'
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.xml_column.getClobVal()
FROM   table_name t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/95f3c/5/0)**:

```
|                T.XML_COLUMN.GETCLOBVAL() |
|------------------------------------------|
| <XML>
  <FRUIT_SHOP>AZHAGIRI</FRUIT_SHOP>
  <FRUITS>
    <FRUIT>
      <FRUIT_NAME>ORANGE</FRUIT_NAME>
        <ORANGE_FIELDS>
        <FIELD>
          <KEY>COLOUR</KEY>
          <VALUE>LIGHT_RED</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD>
          <KEY>WEIGHT</KEY>
          <VALUE>2KG</VALUE>
        </FIELD>
      </ORANGE_FIELDS>
    </FRUIT>
  </FRUITS>
  </XML>
```